# Finding the fixed point of a 1 dimensional map.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I am struggling with finding the fixed point x* as a function of r for the one dimensional map:
$$x_{n+1}=f(x)=x_n+log(r(2-x_n))$$
The solution is apparently:
$$x_n^*=2-1/r$$
I understand a fixed point as fulfilling $$f(x_n^*) = x^*_n$$ but I am really struggling with figuring out how you're suppose to analytically find it for equations such as the one above.

Comment: Well, if $f(x^*) = x^*$ then, using formula on $f(x)$ you get that $log(r(2-x^*)) = 0$ and hence $r(2-x^*) = 1$. From this you get the formula.